# Fit a curve using matplotlib on loglog scale

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting simple 2D graph using loglog function in python as follows:

```
plt.loglog(x,y,label='X vs Y');
```

X and Y are both lists of floating numbers of `n` size.

I want to fit a line on the same graph. I tried numpy.polyfit , but I am getting nowhere.

How do you fit a line using polyfit if your graph is already in loglog scale?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Numpy doesn't care what the axes of your matplotlib graph are.

I presume that you think `log(y)` is some polynomial function of `log(x)`, and you want to find that polynomial? If that is the case, then run [`numpy.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html#numpy-polyfit) on the logarithms of your data set:

```
import numpy as np
logx = np.log(x)
logy = np.log(y)
coeffs = np.polyfit(logx,logy,deg=3)
poly = np.poly1d(coeffs)
```

`poly` is now a polynomial in `log(x)` that returns `log(y)`. To get the fit to predict `y` values, you can define a function that just exponentiates your polynomial:

```
yfit = lambda x: np.exp(poly(np.log(x)))
```

You can now plot your fitted line on your matplotlib `loglog` plot:

```
plt.loglog(x,yfit(x))
```

And show it like this

```
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to go through the basic of polynomial fitting, i was having trouble with coeff and yfit

Comment: So here we took a 3rd degree polynomial in log x that fits with log y. and then calculated new values of y taking exponential of f(logx). I plotted using ax.plot so not on log scale. It actually worked on my data. But I don't get why?

Comment: @Pretty I am not sure I understand your comment. You fitted a polynomial to (log(x), log(y)) data and then plotted x vs. y? Why would you expect that not to work? If log(y) = P(log(x)), where P is some polynomial, then y = exp(P(log(x)) = yfit(x), by definition of yfit. Plotting plt.plot(x,yfit(x)) will show a good fit, provided P itself is a good fit for the logs of the data.

Answer (score 1):

`np.log(x)` extracts the natural logarythm, so the fitting of the above solution is done on natural logs, while `plt.loglog` draws on 10-base logs.

Both operations should be run in the same base:

```
logx = np.log10(x)
logy = np.log10(y)
```

and

```
yfit = lambda x: np.power(10, poly(np.log(x)))
```

or

```
yfit = lambda x: 10**(poly(np.log(x)))
```